# Consuming More than One SOAP Web Service in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-boot

I've followed this guide to consume my first webservice: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

It's ok and working.

But now I need to add another webservice. And I've tried to create another Marshaller configuration file, but when springboot starts it loads only one marshall configuration.

Anyone knows how can I use more than one marshaller?

I've tried to use the same Marshal configuration file as below:
    package checkverification.atmncn;

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
public class AtmNcnClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPaths("checkverification.atmncn.wsdl.test", "checkverification.atmncn.wsdl.live");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public AtmNcnLiveClient atmNcnLiveClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        AtmNcnLiveClient client = new AtmNcnLiveClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://ws.paymentsgateway.net/pg");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public AtmNcnTestClient atmNcnTestClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        AtmNcnTestClient client = new AtmNcnTestClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://ws.paymentsgateway.net/pgtest");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to use the client, I'm receiving a cast exception:

```
[Internal Server Error]
checkverification.atmncn.wsdl.live.ExecuteSocketDelimitedQueryResponse cannot be cast to 
checkverification.atmncn.wsdl.test.ExecuteSocketDelimitedQueryResponse
```

So I think I need only one marshaller and configure more than one webservice for this marshaller... but I can't figure out how can I do that...

PS: The two webservice has the same methods and classes, but different urls (one for test and other for production). So maybe it's causing the cast exception...

My working class is a controller, it's very long so I will paste only the main code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cvapi")
public class TransactionApiController {

    @Autowired
    AtmNcnTestClient atmNcnTestClient;

    @Autowired
    AtmNcnLiveClient atmNcnLiveClient;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> submit(@RequestBody @Valid Transaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) {

        // a lot of code with the controller logic...

            // Do a Test Post
            if(as.getTestMode() || licenseNumberType == VerifyType.TEST) {
                checkverification.atmncn.wsdl.test.ExecuteSocketDelimitedQueryResponse res =
                        atmNcnTestClient.executeSocketDelimitedQueryResponseTest(params); // ---->>> ERROR IN THIS LINE

                atmNcnResultWrapper = AtmNcnParameterBuilder.getResult(
                        res.getExecuteSocketDelimitedQueryResult());
            } else {
                // Live Post
                checkverification.atmncn.wsdl.live.ExecuteSocketDelimitedQueryResponse res =
                        atmNcnLiveClient.executeSocketDelimitedQueryLive(params);

                atmNcnResultWrapper = AtmNcnParameterBuilder.getResult(
                        res.getExecuteSocketDelimitedQueryResult());
            }

    // a lot of code to generate the response

    } // end of method

}
```

Comment: How does look your working class ?

Comment: thanks for the interest @reos, I've placed my working code above and the line with error.